# const char [22]' to 'LPCWSTR'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, type-conversion

```
error C2664: 'MessageBoxW' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'const char [22]' to 'LPCWSTR'
     Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

i am trying to execute this code below and getting error as above.

```
bool RegistryHandler::readRegistryEntry(String^ referencePath, String^ keyName, String ^keyValue)
{
    HKEY keyHandle;
    LPCTSTR sk = TEXT("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Office\\Outlook\\Addins\\GoToApp");
    wchar_t  rgValue [1024];
    wchar_t fnlRes [1024];
    DWORD size1;
    DWORD Type;
    if( RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sk,0,KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &keyHandle) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
         {
            size1=1023;
            RegQueryValueEx( keyHandle,L"ApplicationUrl", NULL, &Type,(LPBYTE)rgValue,&size1);
            MessageBoxW(NULL,L"inside for readindg",L"Native Addin",MB_OK);
            MessageBoxW(NULL,rgValue, "Product ID of Windows", MB_OK);
         }     
    else {
            MessageBoxW(NULL,L"inside for else",L"Native Addin",MB_OK);     
         }
    RegCloseKey(keyHandle);
    return true ;
}
```

how to get rgvalue correctly ???

plse help new to Vc++

Comment: You're missing an 'L' in front of "Product ID of Windows"

Comment: rgValue is a variable .. i cant add L tre directly to execute that code
i have to convert that to display.

Comment: MessageBoxW(NULL,rgValue, L"Product ID of Windows", MB_OK);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is missing "L" before "Product ID of Windows" string. It should be:

```
MessageBoxW(NULL,rgValue, L"Product ID of Windows", MB_OK);
```